# Deploying a ClickOnce Application and Trial Versioning

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I've developed a small application that I'm deploying using ClickOnce.

For now, the only type of license that is available for the program is a Trial version.

The problem is that, if a user installs the program and the trial expires, they could just use the same files they downloaded to re-install the program without having to go back to my website to re-download the program.

The program is free, but I would like users of the program to re-visit the website to download the program again.

The way that I'm detecting if the trial has expired is from the time the user installs the program, they have one month to use it. After a month has gone by, the program locks itself.

How could I make the program, such that they couldn't use the same setup files to re-install the program after the trial version has expired?

Comment: You could add a key to the registry from the setup and check if the key matches if so you can stop the user from running the same setup file.

Comment: That's right. But if you find it difficult to implement such logic in installer, you may add similar logic inside your program. Such that, the program should write expiration information in registry, or retrieve and validate that info on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx).

But if you don't make regular update of your installer, you won't be able to identify a difference between the two installer !